# Force portlet render from other port let in Liferay 6.0.6

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

Is there any way I can force the render of a port let in Liferay?

I'm using Liferay 6.0.6 and I want to set a value into a session variable and force other port let to render to be able to update fragment of this second portlet as it reads this variable.

In the portlet development I am using JSF 2.0 (Mojarra) and PrimeFaces

In case this is impossible. Any other suggestion to achieve it? How can two port lets communicate to update a fragment of one of them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a Google for **Ajax Push** in PrimeFaces, and you will find some resources. Ajax Push can also be used in a portlet context. We've been using Ajax Push in ICEfaces, but it [seems](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chat.jsf) that PrimeFaces supports the same. I did however came across [this](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3207) issue, but I don't know if it's still relevant for the version you're using at the moment.

Comment: Thanks limburger. I mark this answer as resolved because while attending an IceFaces Training Webinar this solution came onto the scenario. It was before you answered it but thanks anyway. This solution works. At the moment PrimePush is still under hard development and haven't worked for some examples I tried.